# Volley not attaching parameters to my url via POST request with StringRequest

Tags: android, parameters, http-post, android-volley

I am trying to use volley to add a score to my database. I have tested my URL with a POST request using Postman, I have also manually typed the URL with parameters in the android app to the POST request, and that works. so I assume that my issue is in my android code? Or do I have to use the getParams to manually build the url string?

the error I'm getting from my backend: 
Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'undefined' in 'field list'

which makes me think that my parameters aren't getting initialized prior to the StringRequest being called.

```
public void submitHighScore(){
    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // response
                    Toast.makeText(context, response , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // error
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Error: unable to submit Score " + error , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
    ){@Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError
        {
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("playerName", "Android test");
            params.put("playerScore", "3000");

            return params;
        }
    };

    HighScoreSingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(postRequest);
```

For those who may or may not believe me about my code on my server side.

```
app.post('/api/highScore', function(req,res){
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "xxxx",
        user: "xxxx",
        password: "xxxx",
        database: "xxxx"
    });
    if(req.query!=null){ //
        console.log(typeof req.query.playerName);
    con.query(`INSERT INTO xxxx (playerScore, playerName) VALUES
            (${req.query.playerScore}, "${req.query.playerName}" )`, // async, runs callback aka function
         function(err,rows){
            if(err) throw err;
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
            res.send('Updated High Score');
        });

    con.end();
    }
});
```

Thank you in advance, It's very possible I'm overlooking something very simple, otherwise I will just modify my URL in my StringRequest as this seems a bit silly, given the getParams method.

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this will work for you.

I think you need to add header

Override this method.

```
@Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String,String> params =  super.getHeaders();
        if(params==null)params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("Content-Type","text/plain");
        return params;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. As I am new to the backend development, I mistook trying to use the getParams() method to concatenate to the url via a query string, instead of using the body of the message where the parameters are actually stored.